# Hide all rows under this specific value [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql

I have a question, Is it possible in query to hide all rows based on condition like:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║    ProdNo    ║ remains║ = remaining product
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ R0001        ║  60    ║
║  2 ║ R0001        ║  30    ║
║  3 ║ R0001        ║  0     ║
║  4 ║ R0002        ║  100   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

This table, I want to show only the data that still remaining product like R0001 have no remaining product because the last value of R0001 is 0 and R0002 have remaining I want show to query the only remaining product the output expected will be this

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║    ProdNo    ║ remains║ = remaining product
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  4 ║ R0002        ║  100   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

But If ID 3 is not 0 will show all the remaining

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║    ProdNo    ║ remains║ = remaining product
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ R0001        ║  60    ║
║  2 ║ R0001        ║  30    ║
║  3 ║ R0001        ║  30    ║
║  4 ║ R0002        ║  100   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

This is my tested query but seems is not working because the ID 3 is the only one row hiding

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (CASE WHEN(remains != 0) THEN prodNo = R0001)
```

Comment: I really don't get what you actually want.

Comment: I think you may have designed a database that does not really fit your needs. Thats a very odd way of holding a stock total

Comment: @maio290 Sorry, I want to show only the remaining product and hide the same productno if the remainscolumn is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it by using a self-join with one side having a group with a minimum to find the 0s

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74c0ee/5

This is the query

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   Table a 
       JOIN (SELECT prodno, 
                    Min(remains) AS remains 
             FROM   Table 
             GROUP  BY prodno) b 
         ON a.prodno = b.prodno 
            AND b.remains > 0;
```

Comment: This is the expected result I want to met, Thank you for sharing this method :)